# Difference between experiential learning and hands-on learning

Tags: teaching, terminology

I have just started doing some research regarding different ways of teaching and learning.

I would like to know whether experiential learning and hands-on learning are same or there are some differences between them.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. As you should only ask one question per question. As your first question (how relevant are Experiential Learning and Hands-on Learning today) is too opinion-based for this format IMHO and also not addressed by the existing answer, I took the liberty to remove it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thank you for editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

Experiential learning involves metacognative aspects of learning such as the concept of transfer which is the ability to take skills from one setting and use them in another. Often experiential learning includes hands on learning.

Hands on learning usually lacks the metacognitive characteristics of experiential learning. For example project for the sake of a project without a deeper application. Generally these two terms are used interchangeable when this should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Regarding "concept of transfer "  could you please explain a little bit more? May be using a simple example.

Comment: ie you learn to count and then you take your counting skills to do addition. This is a simple example of transfer